# Counting unique characters in a String given by the user

Tags: java

I have to write a program that counts the uniques characters in a String given by the user. For example "abc" returns 3 and "aabbccd" returns 4. I am not allow to use  advanced Java classes like Map, Set, etc. I can only use arrays, Strings, for loops, while loops, if statements. I am trying to use a nested loop but am getting confused about how to write the algorithm for the second for loop.

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String input){

String orgInput = input.toLowerCase();
        int count = 0;
        int stringLength = input.length();
        for( int i = 0; i<stringLength; i++){
            for(int j = 2; j > j-i-1; j--){
                char temp = orgInput.charAt(i);
                if (temp == orgInput.charAt(j)){
                    count++;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is extremely easy :)

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String input) {
    boolean[] isItThere = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        isItThere[input.charAt(i)] = true;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < isItThere.length; i++) {
        if (isItThere[i] == true){
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Example for input "aab"

First for-cycle goes 3 times, each time for one char.

Value of "a" is 97, so it turns isItThere[97] to true, then second "a" is involved, which is doing the same, isItThere[97] is set to true again (hence changing nothing).

After that "b" is involved, value of char "b" is 98, therefore isItThere[98] is set to true.

And then you have second for-cycle, where you cycle through the all isItThere array. If you find any true statement, you increment count. In our case, you find isItThere[97] and isItThere[98] as true statement, it means you increment twice and returning 2.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that says that the characters in the String have to be `<= 255`.  So this could give `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, depending on the input.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Ah, tx, I forgot that char is 16-bit in Java.

Comment: Is it not possible to use `new boolean[input.length]`? Or am I overlooking something.

Comment: @skiwi - yea, you are missing something :). I edited answer where I explained what happening.

Answer (score 48):

Using Java 8 you could do the following:

```
public static long countUniqueCharacters(String input) {
    return input.chars()
            .distinct()
            .count();
}
```

This creates an `IntStream` of `char`s, then takes only distincts values and then counts the number of occurences.

Comment: I think he cannot use it, because of restriction of "advanced anything" and dependency of Java 8 (which is out only few days). However nice answer I learn a bit and any further readers will learn too. Vote up!

Answer (score 4):

Here another solution:

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String input) {
    String buffer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (!buffer.contains(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
            buffer += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return buffer.length();
}
```

The first occurance of each character is stored in `buffer`. Therefore you have of all characters one in `buffer`, therefore `buffer.length()` delivers the count you need.

Answer (score 4):

If your stuck on Java 7, you can use an ArrayList and just add unique values to it, then return the size of the ArrayList, which should always work even if the count is zero.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public int getUniqeCount( String arg )
 {
     ArrayList<Character> unique = new ArrayList<Character>();
     for( int i = 0; i < arg.length(); i++)
         if( !unique.contains( arg.charAt( i ) ) )
             unique.add( arg.charAt( i ) );
     return unique.size();
 }
```

Comment: Though this works, it's terribly inefficient. You should use a HashSet. This way you are doing O(1) when calling contains. As a matter of fact, calling contains is unnecessary on a Set because sets drop duplicates for you.

Comment: Thanks taylor, actually after some performance tweaks I did to a similar problem I realized I could use bit manipulation, and an extra integer. Something along the lines of converting the char to an int and adding a 1 bit on the counter. 

pseduo-code ***
int counter = 0;
char c = ... for c in String
counter = (counter << (int)c) & 1; 

or something, along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int countUniqueChars (String buf) {
    HashSet<Character> hash = new HashSet<>();
    buf = buf.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length(); i++)
        hash.add(buf.charAt(i));
    return hash.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are allowed to use Java Sets, The following code is readable, compact and doing the job smoothly

```
public static int countUniqueChar(String word){
    Set<Character> wordSet = new HashSet<>();
    for(Character c : word.toCharArray())
        wordSet.add(c);
    return wordSet.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString = "";

for(int i=0; i< word.length(); i++) {
    if(myString.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == -1) {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
        myString = myString + word.charAt(i);
    }
}
return myString.length();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long calculateDistinctSubStringSum(String text) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    char[] charAarry = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charAarry.length; i++) {
        map.put(charAarry[i] + "", 1);
    }
    return map.size();

}
```

This is what I did to calculate but I am still looking for any fast way. If anyone knows please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet collections for counting the unique elements in a string. It allow only unique element.

**Code Snippet**

```
public static int uniqueCount(String str) 
{
   HashSet<Character> al = new HashSet<Character>();
   char[] arr= str.toCharArray();
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
   {
      al.add(arr[i]);  
   }
   return al.size() ;
}
```

Refer this link to get full code: [ideone](http://ideone.com/2NIN8V)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the following code helps you:

```
String myString = "";

for(int i=0; i< word.length(); i++) {

    if(myString.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == -1) {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
        myString = myString + word.charAt(i);
    }
}
return myString.length();
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter String:");
    int length = scanner.nextInt();
    char[] ch1 =  new char[length];
    String[] input = new String[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String userInput = scanner.next();
        input[i] = userInput;
         ch1= userInput.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(ch1);
         System.out.println(ch1);
    }
```

Comment: you should add some details to your  answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Unique Characters In A String:

This is a basic Java interview subject, where the interviewer wants to check the knowledge 
of HashSet or indexOf(in case of Java 7) .
Let's take up a question. 
Let's say the interview tells you to
Check if the String is unique : 
HashSet ensures uniqueness ,In other words , every object in the HashSet presents only once.
Hence, we will use HashSet.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Abc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Gini";
    String aa = a.toLowerCase();
       if(  isUnique(aa)   ) {
              System.out.println("All characters are unique");
       }else {
           System.out.println("All characters  are not unique");
       }
}
public static boolean isUnique(String a ) {
    Set< Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    char[] charArray =a.toCharArray();
    for(Character ch :charArray) {
        if(!set.add(ch)) {
            return false;
        }//if
    }//foreach
        return true;
}
}
```

The output in case of GINI will be : All characters  are not unique

Now, the count of the unique characters.
Here also we will use HashSet because of the uniqueness.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class practice11 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Gini";
    String aa = a.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(aa));  
}
public static int  countUniqueCharacters(String a) {
    char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();

    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i< charArray.length ; i++) {

         set.add(charArray[i]);
    }//for
    return   set.size() ;//This will give 3
}
}
```

The output for Gini will be 3 (Gin will be considered) .

indexOf Method :
indexOf() returns the index of first occurrence of the character and then we are comparing with -1.

```
public class Abc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Gini";
    String aa = a.toLowerCase();
    String t = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.length(); i++) {
            int  pp =   aa.charAt(i) ;

        if(t.indexOf(aa.charAt(i))  ==  -1  ) {
            t = t + aa.charAt(i);
        }//if


    }//for

    System.out.println(t );// This will give => gin
    System.out.println(t.length()); // this will give 3
}//main
}//end
```

In Java 8, this is extremely easy. We just have to use chars().distinct().count().
But the return type will be long.

```
class Abc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Gini";
        String aa = a.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(  countUnique(aa));
    }

    private static long  countUnique(String aa) {
        // this will give 3(gin. another i will be not be counted as we have used distinct())
         return  aa.chars().distinct().count() ; 
    }
}
```

Another classic Interview Question : Find the First non repeating character in the String OR the First Unique Character in a String. This problem can be solved using the knowledge of HashMap.

```
class Abc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String a = "GinaRani" ;
// Output will be G
          System.out.println( firstNonRepeatingCharacter(a) );

    }//main
    public static Character firstNonRepeatingCharacter(String a){
      Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        for(    Character  ch   :     charArray){
               if( map.containsKey(ch)   )   {
                    map.put(ch, map.get(ch) +1 ) ;
               } else{
                   map.put(ch, 1);
               }
        }//for

        // 1st non repeating character

        for( int  i = 0 ; i < a.length(); i ++ ){
             char chh = a.charAt(i);
             if(  map.get(chh) == 1 ){
                 System.out.println("first non repeating character in the String is  : ");
                   return chh ; 
             }//if
        }//for

        return null; 

    }//firstNonRepeatingCharacter
}//end
```

We will do this with the help of list comprehension in Python. We are not using set() operator.
In Python :

```
string = 'GiniGinaProtijayi'

unique = []

[ unique.append(ch)  for ch in string if ch not in unique ]
lengthofUniqueCharacters = len(unique)
print("length of Unique Characters => " ,lengthofUniqueCharacters)
print("as a list => ",unique)
print("as a string => " , ''.join(unique))
```

Just to print out the distinct characters in Java 8:

```
public class Test5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "GinaGini";

        String aa = a.chars().distinct()
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
                        StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
        System.out.println(aa);//Gina

    }// main

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use advanced JAVA classes like this:

```
int solution(String s) {
    return (int) s.chars().distinct().count();
}
```

You can count each character in its own array index by ASCII:

```
int solution(String s) {
    //1. Create a ASCII char array
    //2. count chars into array.
    //3. loop array and return count of each greater than 0
    
    int[] a = new int[128];
    
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        a[s.charAt(i)] += 1;
    
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if(a[i] > 0)
            count += 1;
        
    return count;
}
```