# Java - get index ids from array by value

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public int index(String character)
{
    String[] array = {"Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange"};
    return Integer.parseInt(array.indexOf(character));
}
```

And then:

```
testClass ind = new testClass();
for (loop probably here)
{
    System.out.println(ind.index("Apple"));
}
```

And result should be:

**0 2**

But I don't know where I should put loop and what should be in loop. Without loop is result only first index id - in this case it would be 0.

Comment: Why are you parsing index which is an int anyway. And it returns the first index... indexOf that is... what is the point of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, that is true, sorry. Can you tell me where I should put loop?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this ? What should be the input and what should be the output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179001/find-all-the-indexes-of-an-item-within-a-list-using-stream-api

Comment: There is no such function as indexOf on arrays so it won't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want to do with your code... But the way you can get 0 2 as an output is...

```
static String[] array = {"Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
          if(array[i].equals("Apple"))
             System.out.println(i);
}
```

Not sure what your goal is with your code... so that's the most I can give you

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted! And if I would have this:         System.out.println(new String("acac").indexOf("a"));, how can I get 0 and 2? Again number of position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597527/counting-unique-characters-in-a-string-given-by-the-user

Comment: I don't need get count of unique characters, but number positions of letter in string.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = Arrays.asList(list).indexOf("element to search");
```

Comment: This is a waste of resources

Comment: I just worte a small program to test it. Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("xxx"); is much faster. (~factor 10) sure it needs more resources but a list is still a very datatype, so you wouldn't recognize it

Comment: It would be nice to have some sort of explanation of what you're doing here.

Comment: `  int elem = 10000;
  String[] array = new String[elem];
  long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i=0; i < elem; i++) array[i] =((int)( Math.random()*5000))+"";
  
       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
           if(array[i].equals("15")){
              System.out.println(i);
              break;
           }
       System.out.println("As Array:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()- start));
   start= System.currentTimeMillis();
      int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf("15");

      System.out.println("As List:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()- start));`

Comment: Sorry im new here thought `` will mark this as a code